# Complex view based off of Node Reference

Tags: views, nodes

Drupal 7

1. Is it possible to get the current pages Node name and dynamically use it for a view using node reference? I have a content type called product and I am going to add a view to this content type that will show a list of image content types that have a node reference field set to the product content type.

For example:

```
"Furniture" page - content type "Product"
"Clothing" page - content type "Product"

"Image" content type - "Image 1" w/ a node reference field of "Furniture"
"Image" content type - "Image 2" w/ a node reference field of "Clothing"
"Image" content type - "Image 3" w/ a node reference field of "Clothing"
"Image" content type - "Image 4" w/ a node reference field of "Furniture"
```

So when I go to the Furniture product page my view will have Image 1 and Image 4 in the list
and if I got to Clothing product page it will show Image 2 and Image 3.

If this needs more explanation please let me know.

Comment: It will easy to do, if you use taxonomy for your categories, like clothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the node reference field as a relationship. That will enable the node reference field to be added as a contextual filter.

You can use [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva) module to attach the view to your node page, which will automatically pass the node ID to the view (which your contextual filter should pick up and show only images referencing that node).

You can checkout [Is there a good tutorial for "Entity Views Attach Module"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-entity-views-attach-module) for more info on [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva)

Comment: Great I will take a look at the tutorial. +1